# Filling ChartView with populated serie from c++

Tags: qt, qml, qchartview

I need to fill QML ChartView with LineSeries. I am doing it by invoking method from c++:

```
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_chartview, "createSeries", Qt::DirectConnection,
                          Q_RETURN_ARG(QAbstractSeries *, serie),
                          Q_ARG(int, type),
                          Q_ARG(QString, ("Chart "+QString::number(index+1))),
                          Q_ARG(QAbstractAxis *, axis_x),
                          Q_ARG(QAbstractAxis *, axis_y));
```

and then appending points to created serie:

```
if(QLineSeries *line_serie = qobject_cast<QLineSeries *>(serie)){
    static std::default_random_engine e;
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 3);
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        line_serie->append(i, dis(e));
    }
}
```

It's working fine with small number of data, but extremely slow with large number of data.
The problem is that each 'append' triggers redrawing. So my question is: is there any way to add serie to ChartView only after it has been populated with points?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Does this help?  ```append(const QList<QPointF> &points)``` or ```void QXYSeries::replace(QList<QPointF> points)```

Comment: With 'append' nothing change with loading time - it is still slow, with 'replace' it works nice and fast even with large number of points. Thanks!